# A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause... Datagridview

Tags: c#, linq

The error raised

> A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause

```
List<DataGridViewRow> selectedRows = 
    (from row in DataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
     where Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells("CheckBoxColumn").Value) == true).ToList();
```

Comment: You have no SELECT clause for your query.

Comment: Well, you get that error because *"A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause"*... Why don't you just add one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change this

```
from row in DataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
where Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells("CheckBoxColumn").Value) == true
```

to this

```
from row in DataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
where Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells("CheckBoxColumn").Value) == true
select row
```

It is remarkable that you would have the same result if you have written the whole query in the following syntax:

```
var selectedRows = DataGridView1.Rows
                                .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                                .Where(row => Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells("CheckBoxColumn").Value) == true)
                                .ToList();
```

Comment: I got this error Cannot implicitly convert type datagridview''. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 1):

When writing a linq query in query syntax it must have a [`select` clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384087.aspx) to it:

```
var result = from item in collection
             select item;
```

In your case:

```
var result = (from row in DataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
              where Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells("CheckBoxColumn").Value)
              select row).ToList();
```

*Notice that doing `Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells("CheckBoxColumn").Value) == true` is redundant as `Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells("CheckBoxColumn").Value)` is already a boolean*